# how to get 5 categories from category table and get 4 post of each category in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a table named `categories` and a table named `courses`. These tables have one-to-many relation, it means each course belongs to one category and each category has many courses.
Now, I want to get five `categories` (order is not important yet) and 4 `courses` for each of these categories. I tried some of the solutions on stackoverflow and around the web but none of them worked! One of them (the below code) gets 4 courses for first item only!

```
$result = Category::with(['courses' => function ($query) {
    $query->take(4);
})->take(5)->get();
```

I solved this problem with for loop, but I wonder if laravel has its solution for this.
I'll be appreciated for your answers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a laravel package specialized in this called [Eloquent Eager Limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit):

after installing it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

you should use it inside the models that would apply limited eager loading:

```
class Category extends Model
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
 // ........
}

class Course
extends Model
{

use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
 // ........
}
```

now this query will get the result you want:

```
   $result = Category::with(['courses' => function ($query) {
    $query->take(4);
})->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: Yes! this is what I want. I really expected laravel to have this feature!! Thank you. :)

Comment: Wow, super interesting. I would have expected `Model::has('relations', '>=', 4)->with(['relations' => function ($query){ $query->limit(4); }])->limit(5)->get();` (similar to the deleted answers below) to return 5 `Model` instances, each with 4 `Relation` instances, but only the first Model has 4, the rest have 0. Great find on this question and solution!